My Google Geospatial AR app is stuck in Initializing Geospatial Functionalities
private const string _localizationInitializingMessage = "Initializing Geospatial functionalities.";

// Check earth state.
var earthState = EarthManager.EarthState;
 if (earthState == EarthState.ErrorEarthNotReady)
  {
    SnackBarText.text = _localizationInitializingMessage;
     return;
   }

This is from the geospatial controller script. it returns Initializing Geospatial functionalities. but im stuck in this screen and i cant figure out why my app is in earth is not ready state. it was running before but its not now.
I tried setting:
Custom Main Manifest, Custom Base Gradle Template, Custom Gradle Properties Template, Custom Gradle Settings Template in Publishing Settings. Then Force Resolve in Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android Resolver.
and this made my app work before and now its not. please help thank you

I had the same issue with my AR Geospatial app, I fixed it by changing the Authority setting to Latitude Longitude Height in the Cesium Georeference component.
Cesium component example
